# Axios fetch with parameter not working in nexjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, next.js

I am working with nextjs,I am getting "input text"(email) value in console successfully and i am trying to use this value
as "parameter value" but instad of "dynamic value(email)", "{emails}" is saving in database,In other words I want to know that
how can i use "parameter value" (dynamic) and why not my success or error message is displaying ?

i tried with following code for use "dynamic value"

```
const emails = email; // getting email id successfully and i am trying to append as shown below
const res = await fetch('https://example.com/serge/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email={emails}');
```

And second problem is "i am not gettting success or failure message after click on subscribe button"
I tried with following code

```
{success 
                       ? 
                    <span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-green-700"> 
                         {success}
                    </span> 
                       : 
                    <span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-red-800">
                          {error} 
                    </span>
                }
```

Here is my full code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Subscribe = () => {
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
 const [error, setError] = useState('');
 const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');

const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
            
            console.log('data is '+email);  
            const emails = email;
            console.log('emails id is '+emails);    
            
            event.preventDefault();
            const res = await fetch('https://exmple.com/serge/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email={emails}');
            
            const { error, message } = await res.json();
            if (error) {
                    setError(error);
            } else {
                    setSuccess(message);
            }
};
    const changeEmail = (event) => {
        const email = event.target.value;
        setEmail(email);
    }
   return (
                <form className="row g-3" onSubmit={subscribeMe}>
                <div className="col-12">
                <input type="subscribe" className="form-control" id="subscribe2" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Please Subscribe" onChange={changeEmail}
                />

              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-3">subscribe</button>
              </div>
                {success 
                       ? 
                    <span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-green-700"> 
                         {success}
                    </span> 
                       : 
                    <span className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-red-800">
                          {error} 
                    </span>
                }

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have the set name as per the DB field value otherwise you have to change it before sending it to the API call.

second, your email value does not pass into API because you use a string in API URL you have to change this till sign `` pass emails value inside $ sign that I will show you below code.

```js
const res = await fetch(`https://exmple.com/serge/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email=${emails}`);
```

Comment: "success" or "failure" msg not showing in page

Comment: can you share a log of success and errors so it will help to understand the problem?

Comment: sorry not understand your point

Comment: which response do you get from API?

Answer (score 0):

you have made mistake in template literal

```
const subscribeMe = async (event) => {
            
            console.log('data is '+email);  
            const emails = email;
            console.log('emails id is '+emails);    
            
            event.preventDefault();
            const res = await fetch(`https://exmple.com/serge/admin-panel/Api/subscribe?email=${emails}`);
            
            const { error, message } = await res.json();
            if (error) {
                    setError(error);
            } else {
                    setSuccess(message);
            }
};
```

Comment: my success or failure msg not showing